# Opal: How do I create a singleton global between frames?

Tags: javascript, ruby, singleton, frames, opalrb

I'm building a javascript application using [Opal.rb](http://opalrb.org/). The application is made up by a couple of frames responsible for different parts of the application. The problem I have is that I have objects instantiated in x_frame that I need to access from my y_frame. The way I do this now is by writing:

`window.top.frames.x_frame.Opal.MyClass.$do_something()`

But this gets ugly. Is there any way I could define a singleton that is globally accessible for all frames?

Comment: Just define whatever you want in global scope (on `window` object.)

Comment: But how would you do that with Opal so that #new instantiates an object on window object?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you don something like this:

```
Document.ready? do
  window = Native(`window`)
  window[:myvar] = MyClass.new
end
```